# Add-in framework for .NET application

Tags: .net, frameworks, add-in

Could you please give me some tips/web site regarding a software architecture to allow a .Net application to be ready for add-in (allow  third partners to develop add-in to plug on top of application)

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [System.Addin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.aspx) namespace on MSDN

Start there, play with that. Then I would also recommend you look at [Mono.Addins](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Addins). You can even look at the Mono.Addins SVN trunk to see how the implementations work on the *inside*. You will need to understand how interfaces and attributes play a vital role in making your plugin architecture work.

The [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mef) may still be under development, but it is worthwhile to become familiar with it as Johannes points out. If your team is uncomfortable in moving forward with MEF for your production project, at the very least, have some knowledge with the framework.

Answer (score 3):

There are complete frameworks built around this idea. One of the most popular is the [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mef) by Microsoft. It is open source btw.

Comment: Downside on MEF is that it's currently only available for .Net 4.0: http://www.codeplex.com/MEF

Comment: MEF is under developpment ... not an option for a production application

Comment: Which open source application isn't? Which production software isn't? Whether it is stable or not, that's what counts. The rest is politics.

Comment: .NET 4 is at release candidate level, with release about 6 weeks away. MEF was also used for Visual Studio itself. I'd say that MEF is ready for consideration in a production application, if that application is ready to move to .NET 4.

Comment: I wanted to note for readers that the .NET Framework now contains a System.Composition namespace that incorporates what used to be the MEF project. The MEF project is considered an unstable research project now, the stable version of which has been rolled into the BCL.